# Повторное открытие окна на C#

Tags: c#

После закрытия окна нужно повторно открыть окно хрома.
driver.close();
Можно ли открыть его и как , на языке C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам стоит дополнить ваш вопрос, подробно описать задачу и в чем состоит проблема!

Если я вас правильно понял то вам нужно подписаться на событие закрытия окна и выполнить этот код :

```cs
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "google.com" + " --new-window";
process.Start();
```

Подписываюсь на ваш вопрос, после правок отредактирую свой ответ если этот не решит вашу задачу